# Call a perl module's method from a string

Tags: perl

Given a perl module Foo.pm with methods aSub() and bSub()

```
my $obj = Foo->new();
my $x = $obj->aSub($argA);
my $y = $obj->bSub($argB);
```

I have a TAP program where I build an array of hashes:

```
my $test_case = [
   'aSub' => "foobar",
   'bSub' => "whobar"
];
```

I would like to be able to parse the array and use the key/value elements to call methods on the Foo object $obj;
Like a static method:

```
if ($key eq 'aSub') {
  $obj->aSub($value)
} elsif ($key eq 'bSub') {
  $obj->bSub($value);
}
...
```

I would prefer to do this polymorphically so I don't have to hard code the methods:

```
$obj->{$key}($value) #or something of the sort
```

I have tried several methods using references and/or glob, but I keep on getting an error:

> Error: Threw an exception: aSub is not defined

*Test::Harness capturing the error and printing less useful message?*

Comment: `$test_case` as you defined it is not an array of hashes, it's just an array of strings (it's the same as `$test_case = [qw(aSub foobar bSub whobar)]`).

Comment: very good.  My actual array looks like [<scalar>, <hash>, <scalar>..].  My everything was looking like a scalar to my test, so it was never reaching the proper point.  The exception/error must be getting thrown  by the module Foo that is trying to interpret 'aSub' as a valid argument to $obj->bSub($target);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling a method whose name is in a variable is easy:

```
my $key = 'aSub';
my $value = 'foobar';
my $obj = Foo->new();

$obj->$key($value);
```

Comment: This is correct, though the source of the error was really in my data structure. Since you pointed that out as well, I think you deserve the win.